# Preventing a Shortcut on the Start Menu from Being Highlighted installshield 2012

Tags: installshield, shortcut, installshield-2012

My Basic MSI project aims to install two different shortcuts in the Windows startup menu:

- one advertised shortcut which proceeds to repair if something is wrong whith the software installation (reset accidentaly removed DLLs for example). This shortcut is only used by the support team if something gone wrong.
- one not-advertised shortcut which is the mainly used by the user

After installation, the repair shortcut is highlighted in the startup menu but the main shortcut isn't.

I specify here having tested these manipulations on a Windows Seven operating system with Windows Installer version> = 5.0

- I tried the solution from the [Installshield Documentation](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/SettingShellShtctProp.htm) which consists to add a spécific Shell Shortcut Property

**Repair Shortcut settings:**
Shell Shortcut Property

```
Key Name = System.AppUserModel.ExcludeFromShowInNewInstall
value = 1
```

It doesn't work. The repair Shortcut is still highlighted after install.

- I tried to set the System.AppUserModel.ID property first like [this link](https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?202044-Prevent-shortcut-pinning/page2) indicates

**Repair Shortcut settings:**
Shell Shortcut Property

```
Key Name = System.AppUserModel.ID
value = 1
Key Name = System.AppUserModel.ExcludeFromShowInNewInstall
value = 1
```

It doesn't work,The repair Shortcut is still highlighted after install on the same configuration.

My main objective is to prevent the repair shortcut from being Highlighted and to activate shortcut highlighting for the main shortcut only.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a useful description. If you want help you should describe what happens, and on what target systems, and how you've tried to diagnose it. (The MsiShortcutProperty table is only supported by some versions of Windows Installer, so that may be relevant.)

Comment: Sorry for this abstraction. I edited my question with those details. I tried to diagnose it on Windows Seven  with Windows Installer in version > 5.0 which is indeed a requirement. Sorry, I try to be as accurate as possible.